How to match Laravel models with multiple conditions using one query
I am building a Laravel application where I keep track of the earned commissions of sales agents within my company. Everytime a sale is made a record is created in the scores database table (Score model). Because the way the commissions are calculated can change from time to time I also have a database table which holds the start and end dates and the associated commissions. The tables look like this:
scores



id
scored_at




1
2024-01-01 00:00:00


2
2024-02-01 00:00:00


3
2024-02-15 00:00:00


4
2023-12-01 00:00:00



commission_rules



id
start
end




1
2024-01-01 00:00:00



2
2024-02-01 00:00:00
2024-02-14 00:00:00


3
2024-02-01 00:00:00




For efficienty reasons I want to run one query which gives me an array with scores.id and commission_rules.id. Right now I am creating the array by looping through all the scores and run a query to the commission_rules table for each score to find the associated rule. But since the scores table has 10k+ entries it takes quite a long time. In case there are multiple matching commission rules for a score I want to return the rule with the highest id and in case there is no rule found I want to return null.
So the array should look something like this:
[
  [ 'id' => 1, 'commission_rule_id' => 1],
  [ 'id' => 2, 'commission_rule_id' => 3],
  [ 'id' => 3, 'commission_rule_id' => 3],
  [ 'id' => 4, 'commission_rule_id' => null]
]

The Eloquent query I run per score looks like this:
ValueRule::query()
  ->where('start', '<=', $score->scored_at)
  ->where(function ($query) use ($score) {
    $query->where('end', '>=', $score->scored_at)
      ->orWhere('end', '=', null);
            })
  ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
  ->first();

I have already tried using left joins but the problem with that is that this gives a row for each match that is found.

This check is invalid: orWhere('end', '=', null) ... you probably want orWhereNull('end') ? ... checking for null is done by is null or is not null never = because null is never equal to anything. Info about the various where clause options can be found here.

Eloquent is smart enough to convert properly the orWhere('end', '=', null) to or end is null - You can verify this in thinker with a query like:User::where('password', '=', null)->dd()

@TUPKAP ... thanks, I'll have to check that, good to know!

@PaulT. The current check does work but I think yours looks more clear. So I will change it. Thank you!

I would suggest to use a left join for joining the scores and comisison_rules with conditions to match the scored_at with the start and end dates in the comission_rules table. Now you can group by scores.id and select max comission_rules id.

you can achieve the result you want via a subQuery:
Score::query()
  ->select('id')
  ->addSelect([
    'commission_rule_id' => ValueRule::query()
       ->whereColumn('commission_rules.start', '<=', 'scores.scored_at')
       ->where(function ($query) {
         $query->where('commission_rules.end', '>=', 'scores.scored_at')
           ->orWhereNull('commission_rules.end');
       })
       ->latest()
       ->limit(1)
   ])
   ->get();

on top of this you can go one step further and create a dynamic relation based on this calculated 'commission_rule_id' field.
class Score extends Model
{
  public function currentCommisionRule()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(ValueRule::class, 'commission_rule_id');
  }

  public function scopeAddCurrentCommisionRuleField(Builder $query, string $as = 'commission_rule_id')
  {
     if (empty($query->getQuery()->columns) {
       $query->select(); // default * selection
     }
     
     $query->addSelect([
       $as => ValueRule::query()
         ->whereColumn('commission_rules.start', '<=', 'scores.scored_at')
         ->where(function ($query) {
           $query->where('commission_rules.end', '>=', 'scores.scored_at')
             ->orWhereNull('commission_rules.end');
         })
         ->latest()
         ->limit(1)
     ]);
  }

now you can eager load this dynamic relation or query like any other relation, the fact that the 'commission_rule_id' does not exist on the model is hidden behind our custom scope.
Score::query()
  ->with(['currentCommisionRule'])
  ->addCurrentCommisionRuleField()
  ->get()

